# Blender: projecting an image via a spotlight onto a plane

Tags: textures, blender, lighting

I've create a plane with a spot light shining from above onto it. The spot light projects a texture of an image onto the plane. The light shots out at an angle but the texture is projecting in a flat 2d form on the plane.

I expected it to stretch out much like the advertisements you'd see drawn on the pitch during a rugby or cricket match. Any idea how I'd change the way the image is shawn onto the plane?

The image should stretch out with the nearer section looking a bit more narrow than the top far section.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sLpWYM4TWLE) is a good tutorial.

He used an empty transform to control the position and scale of the projection.

Comment: Could you please explain the tutorial in your own words so that if the video is taken down, the info will still be here?

Comment: @JonathanConnell K got it.

Comment: I had a look at the tutorial video.  I'm not sure if it'll be able to rotate and stretch the image being projected.  The video only demo's stretching the projected image.  I'll have a go tomorrow and see if an empty can rotate the image and perhaps I'll have to look at moving the plane around to try and get the image to skew.  Thanks.